# Global variable with OpenMP

Tags: global-variables, openmp

Question on OpenMP for multi-threaded code:

Are all global variables shared by the threads? How does one make certain global variable private to master thread?

Thanks

PS: It is a C code.

Comment: what language, C or fortran? specifics are a bit different for two languages. also, if fortran, are you trying to private common blocks?

Answer (score 0):

if i recall correctly

```
#pragma omp threadprivate
```

global variables are a bit tricky, if they has to be initialized, you have to use copyfirst directive (i think that is correct name). also threadprivate variables may carry a significant penalty, on some implementations variable access becomes a function call.